# Avoiding backspace in EditText afterTextChanged() method

Tags: android, textwatcher, addtextchangedlistener

So, I have implemented a simple replace method that replaces a character just before where the text is changed.

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

     editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);

     if (s.length() == 0)
       return;
       s.replace(editText.getSelectionStart(),editText.getSelectionStart()+1,"PP");

     editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

Since this is effective for all kind of text change, It adds the "PP" even I press the back space button. Is there any way to exclude backspace from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First detect Backspace pressed or not**

then avoid your replace when backspace pressed

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        //Normally assume that Backspace not pressed 
        boolean isNotBackspace = true;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //if current count is grater then before that means char added
            //So if current count is smaller then before that means backspace pressed 
            isNotBackspace = count>before;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
            Log.e("isNotBackButton", isNotBackButton+"");

            if (s.length() == 0) {
                //Edit is here 
                //return; //need to block return; because this preventing
                //from adding  adding addTextChangedListener
                isNotBackButton = true;
            //if not backspace pressed then proceed else no action 
            }else if(isNotBackButton){
                s.replace(editText.getSelectionStart(), editText.getSelectionEnd(), "PP");
            }

            editText.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
 });
```

Comment: Your answer is valid to some point but the thing is once all the typed characters are cleared s.replace() is not executed.

Comment: i didn't mean to say anything bad about your solution, just pointing out the loophole where it does not work. I would gladly accept this solution if this handles the case when user types something and then clears all and retypes.

Comment: what you want to say @AdhikariMadridistaSuman if you enter abcd then press back then it will be abcdPP ?

Comment: if again enter keyword then what will be happen

Comment: @Avinash i mean in the Edittext when user enters something and clear it all and then starts typing again the "pp" is not inserted after each typed character.

Comment: when user clears all character then it should be only PP

Comment: you want to add PP after each char change or end of chatacter?

Comment: you can see here whats not working:  https://imgur.com/a/DbeSSCd

Comment: At list you should add some effort with this code... Here is a simple logic, when your Backspace pressed, it will be 0 length one time.. then your will type something again ... so when it is 0 length, just need to update isNotBackButton = false;

Comment: So, just replace return; with isNotBackButton = true;. I edit the answer. Use that...

Answer (score 0):

You could use global boolean variable which would tell you if the code inside `afterTextChanged()` should be executed.

To do that, you should add `View.onKeyListener()` to your `editText` and in there just add `thatBooleanVariable = keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL;` which will return false if backspace is clicked.

After that, just wrap everything inside `afterTextChanged()` with `if (thatBooleanVariable) { }`.

Comment: As per the documentation View.onKeyListener() will be useful for hardware keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this listener. here:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener

Comment: this would work with any of the regular keyboards, but it might not fully work with i.E. swipe keyboard from swiftkey or keyboards with signs (Chinese keyboard)